# Sitecore fxm Add external website

Tags: sitecore-fxm

I wanted to load angular application which generates dynamic DOM. Experience editor is loading only pre-render element and does not able to load dynamic HTML.

Is there any work around on it to load dynamic dom?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 8 and 9 by default using the SPEAK framework for rendering the sitecore backend and Sitecore experience editor.
If you really want to use React or Angular you may want to look at [Sitecore JSS](https://jss.sitecore.net).